# Apuntar dominio a direccion ip publica

Tags: hosting

Buenas tardes espero puedan ayudarme, acabo de adquirir un dominio en Hostgator y quiero que ese dominio apunte a la ip pública de mi servidor, lo que pasa es que tengo subido una página web en ese servidor y puedo acceder a ella mediante la dirección ip pero quiero acceder a ella mediante el dominio que adquirí, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Tienes que agregar un registro Type A y CNAME en la zonas de DNS, en la documentación de los hosting por lo general están esos ejemplos de configuración. https://soporte-latam.hostgator.com/hc/es-419/articles/216721158--Como-crear-un-registro-A-y-CNAME-para-cPanel-